# Autenticação de usuário com Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, segurança, autenticação

Estou começando a fazer a autenticação de usuários com o *Laravel 4*, como base nesse [**link**](http://www.codediesel.com/frameworks/simple-user-authentication-in-laravel-4/).

Minha duvida e a seguinte, toda rota, eu terei que utilizar deste jeito?

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth'), 'HomeController@index');
```

ou seja, terei que inserir o `array('before' => 'auth')` no meio da rota? 
Não tem como eu fazer isso apenas uma vez e o sistema ir validando se eu estou logado? 
Talvez se colocar no `before` seria a solução?

**Obs:** *Quero fazer isso da forma mais organizada possível.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voce pode criar grupos ..

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function(){
   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
   Route::get('/hello', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
});
```

Documentação oficial  [Route Groups](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups)

Answer (score 2):

O mais organizado possível creio que seja algo como isso,
route:

- Toda as as minhas rotas referente ao panel admin está dentro da filtro com prefixo de admin.
- Dentro do admin temos dois filtros.
- admin.guest, que se tentar acessar alguma rota dentro desse filtro será redirecionado para a rota nomeada de 'admin.home'.
- admin.auth, que se tentar acessar alguma rota dentro desse filtro será redirecionado para a rota nomeada de 'admin.getLogin'.

Confira como está o meu código ( não documentarei aqui para o post não ficar grade e cansativo ).

filters.php

```
Route::filter('admin.guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::route('admin.home');
});

Route::filter('admin.auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::route('admin.getLogin');
        }
    }
});
```

Obs¹: o '\Admin...' que tem em uses na rota é o namespace do meu controller, isso é uma outra forma de organizar mais o código mas não vem ao caso agora
Obs²: o filtro 'csrf' é para autenticação de formulário no laravel, ele verifica se o formulário vem acompanho de um token o o verifica, veja seu filtro no arquivo filters

routes.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Panel Admin
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::group(['before' => 'admin.guest'], function(){
        Route::get('login', [
            'as'    => 'admin.getLogin',
            'uses'  => '\Admin\UsersController@getLogin'
        ]);

        Route::group(['before' => 'crsf'], function(){
            Route::post('login', [
                'as'    => 'admin.postLogin',
                'uses'  => '\Admin\UsersController@postLogin'
            ]);
        });
    });

    Route::group(['before' => 'admin.auth'], function(){
        Route::get('/', [
            'as'    => 'admin.home',
            'uses'  => '\Admin\HomeController@index'
        ]);
    });
});
```

Creio que não ficou muito complicado de você entender.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma, ás vezes, é definir isso na controller, no método __construct():

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth');
    }
```

Desse modo, todos os métodos dessa controller só serão acessados por usuários autenticados. Caso queira abrir uma ou mais exceções a este filtro:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth' => ['except' => ['index', 'show']]));
}
```

ou senão

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth' => ['only' => ['create', 'edit', 'store', 'destroy', 'update']]));
}
```

É interessante também ter filtro csrf no método construtor da BaseController, para se proteger contra ataques CSRF:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
}
```

ou também

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => ['post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']));
}
```